# How to get voice-enabled bot to receive capitalized and punctuated text from Azure Speech Service

Tags: azure, botframework, speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services, speech

I have a voice-enabled client app and bot written in C# that use Azure Speech Service. The bot runs in Azure. The client runs locally. When I talk to the client, the speech service sends the speech-to-text result to the client with full punctuation and capitalization. But it sends the result to the bot stripped: with no capitalization or punctuation.

Example: When I say "That might be true. Why? Who wants to know?" the client receives the text "That might be true. Why? Who wants to know?" from the speech service. The bot receives "that might be true why who wants to know", without punctuation or capitalization.

How can I get the bot to receive the same result that the client receives: text fully punctuated and capitalized?

I have reproduced this behavior using Microsoft's sample code. I followed the [Tutorial: Voice-enable your bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/tutorial-voice-enable-your-bot-speech-sdk):

1. I built the [EchoBot sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/02.echo-bot) and deployed it to Azure .
2. I built the [Windows Voice Assistant Client sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Cognitive-Services-Voice-Assistant/tree/main/clients/csharp-wpf/VoiceAssistantClient) and ran it locally.

This bot and client combination showed the same behavior: The client received capitalized, punctuated text and the bot did not.

The following code snippets show the execution sequence:

The Voice Assistant Client picks up my voice and sends it to the speech service via [the call to *ListenOnceAsync()*](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Cognitive-Services-Voice-Assistant/blob/439001c896c27b3a55c8d4bd3fce6955d660b7d4/clients/csharp-wpf/VoiceAssistantClient/MainWindow.xaml.cs#L38):

```cs
38      private DialogServiceConnector connector = null;
...
308     // Create a new Dialog Service Connector for the above configuration and register to receive events
309     this.connector = new DialogServiceConnector(config, AudioConfig.FromDefaultMicrophoneInput());
310     this.connector.ActivityReceived += this.Connector_ActivityReceived;
311     this.connector.Recognizing += this.Connector_Recognizing;
312     this.connector.Recognized += this.Connector_Recognized;
313     this.connector.Canceled += this.Connector_Canceled;
314     this.connector.SessionStarted += this.Connector_SessionStarted;
315     this.connector.SessionStopped += this.Connector_SessionStopped;
316
317     // Open a connection to Direct Line Speech channel
318     this.connector.ConnectAsync();
...
544     this.connector.ListenOnceAsync();
```

Then the Voice Assistant Client receives the speech-to-text result from the speech service via [the property *activity.Text*](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Cognitive-Services-Voice-Assistant/blob/439001c896c27b3a55c8d4bd3fce6955d660b7d4/clients/csharp-wpf/VoiceAssistantClient/MainWindow.xaml.cs#L400):

```cs
400     private void Connector_ActivityReceived(object sender, ActivityReceivedEventArgs e)
401     {
402         var json = e.Activity;
403         var activity = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Activity>(json);
...
472         this.Messages.Add(new MessageDisplay(activity.Text, Sender.Bot, renderedCards));
```

The EchoBot receives the speech-to-text result from the speech service via [the property *turnContext.Activity.Text*](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/1b180f025d2c233fe496ce2bf2dcd6030cc153a6/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/02.echo-bot/Bots/EchoBot.cs#L12):

```cs
12      public class EchoBot : ActivityHandler
13      {
14          protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
15          {
16              var replyText = $"Echo: {turnContext.Activity.Text}";
```

*Note: The problem does not occur when running the bot locally.* Locally, the bot receives the text with proper punctuation and capitalization. The problem occurs only when the bot runs in Azure. I would expect the local behavior and the Azure behavior to match. Surely this behavior is not by design? This is Microsoft's sample code running.

A workaround: Since the client receives the text correctly punctuated and capitalized, have the client send that text directly to the bot. I don't like this since it would complicate the code and require an extra trip across the internet.

Hoping for a better answer. Thank you.

Comment: Can you please add more details about the bot that you are trying?

Answer (score 0):

I think what is happening is that when the audio is recorded, that is sent and then interpreted by Speech Service and done so without any punctuation (as it ***only*** has audio. It doesn't have any punctuation information and does not want to assume any perhaps?). I'm not sure what the Windows Voice Assistant Client is doing to get it formatted/punctuated correctly.

I don't believe you can do anything other than handle it on the bot side. I would suggest maybe using the Humanizer libraries to revert it to something 'correct'/appropriate.

- https://www.nuget.org/packages/Humanizer
- https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S3BEfCzYPRU

Comment: Thanks for your idea. I am afraid I was not clear. I have now added code snippets and source code links for better clarity. Debugging both the Voice Assistant Client and my own client, I can see that the text from the speech service arrives at the client fully punctuated and capitalized. I could make the client send that text to the bot, but I would rather have the bot get it directly from the speech service. That would save an extra trip across the net.